# Android gps listener

Tags: android, gps, notifications, location

I have built an app where in you take pictures and GPS data of that picture is captured for GPS I implemented service and implemented location listener for it. Its working fine but it drains battery so I am planning to change a Lil bit I will start the GPS service when user decides to take pic in my app.. And remove the listener on picture taken. This works fine provided the button to capture is taken after the GPS search is finished else GPS data accuracy is not there. So I have thought to show a dialog fragment to user saying GPS is initializing and ask user to wait. And once GPS location is set the dialog fragment should disappear and user must be able to take picture by the button provided. My problem is how do I capture the event That GPS search is completed .. I am using built in GPS satellite.